# How to enable AutoTLS in Knative using Terrafom?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, cert-manager, knative, knative-serving

In the Knative [documentation](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/using-auto-tls/#configure-config-certmanager-configmap) for enabling AutoTLS, it says that I need to add this to the `data` block in `config-certmanager` configmap:

```
issuerRef: |
  kind: ClusterIssuer
  name: letsencrypt-issuer
```

The only solution that I can think of is to use a `null_resource` resource with a `kubectl patch` command. However, doing this gives me the following error: `Error running command 'kubectl patch configmap config-certmanager -n knative-serving --type merge --patch '{"data":{"issuerRef":"kind:ClusterIssuer"}}'': exit status 1. Output: Error from server: Invalid JSON Patch`

I've tried to split the command in 2 parts. I also tried using a single `null_resource` for both rows (`kind: ClusterIssuer` and `name: letsencrypt-issuer`

My code:

```
resource "null_resource" "patch_config_certmanager_1" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "kubectl patch configmap config-certmanager -n knative-serving --type merge --patch '{\"data\":{\"issuerRef\":\"kind:ClusterIssuer\"}}'"
    }
    
}
resource "null_resource" "patch_config_certmanager_2" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "kubectl patch configmap config-certmanager -n knative-serving --type merge --patch '{\"data\":{\"issuerRef\":\"name:my-clusterissuer\"}}'"
    }
    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?